# Injecting SCSS variables with Node and Gulp

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gulp

I want compile different css files based on different sass variables.

Im trying to use Gulp to achieve this

```
gulp.task('var 1', function() {
    gulp.src(['styles/vars/var1.scss','styles/client.scss'])
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(concat('clientWithVar1.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
});
```

It doesnt seem to work and im getting a  `Sass` error that a variable doesnt exist.

How can i achieve this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you potentially `@import "vars/var1.scss";` at the top of the `client.scss` file (and remove the references to `var1.scss` from the Gulp task?

Comment: Im specifically leaving out the `@import "vars/var1.scss";` so i can provide different variables and generate different `client.css`. Once i solve this question i will have 4 of those tasks with different variable files and then hopefully one task to combine those 4 and generate 4 different css files with different variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

You have this dir structure: 
- tmp (folder) 
- _var1.scss 
- _var2.scss 
- client.scss

In client.scss add: `@import "./tmp/var.scss`
and add gulp task below, so you just copy and rename scss file with variables that you need and then you can compile your main scss file

```js
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('copy', function() {
   return gulp.src('./styles/_var1.scss')
            .pipe(rename('var.scss'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./styles/tmp'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got a directory structure something like this:

- `vars/var1.scss`
- `vars/var2.scss`
- `vars/var3.scss`
- `vars/var4.scss`
- `styles/1/client.scss`
- `styles/2/client.scss`
- `styles/3/client.scss`
- `styles/4/client.scss`

And in each `client.scss` file you have a corresponding `@import` statement (e.g. `@import "../../vars/var1/.scss";`), you should be able to generate all stylesheets with a single task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('styles/**/client.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
});
```

I *think* this should end up with `public/1/client.css`, `public/2/client.css` etc, but you may have to tweak the `gulp.dest` line to suit.